# NPM error eresolve when installing a package in react native

Tags: react-native, npm, terminal, expo, npm-start

When I try to install a package or even update packages on my expo react native app, i get this error message:

```
@davidguri ➜ /workspaces/EK-Student (main) $ npm i
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @react-aria/tabs@3.0.0-alpha.2
npm WARN Found: react@18.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm WARN   112 more (@callstack/react-theme-provider, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1" from @react-aria/tabs@3.0.0-alpha.2
npm WARN node_modules/@react-aria/tabs
npm WARN   @react-aria/tabs@"3.0.0-alpha.2" from @react-native-aria/tabs@0.2.8
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-native-aria/tabs
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1" from @react-aria/tabs@3.0.0-alpha.2
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-aria/tabs
npm WARN     @react-aria/tabs@"3.0.0-alpha.2" from @react-native-aria/tabs@0.2.8
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-native-aria/tabs
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.7" from react-native-paper@4.12.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-button-toggle-group/node_modules/react-native-paper
npm ERR!       react-native-paper@"^4.9.2" from react-native-button-toggle-group@1.1.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-native-button-toggle-group
npm ERR!         react-native-button-toggle-group@"^1.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.8" from react-native-paper@5.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-paper
npm ERR!       react-native-paper@"^5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   111 more (@react-aria/checkbox, @react-stately/checkbox, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm ERR!   @react-native-community/masked-view@"0.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/masked-view@"0.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/codespace/.npm/_logs/2023-04-01T12_58_50_496Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/codespace/.npm/_logs/2023-04-01T12_58_50_496Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried reinstalling npm, node, expo and even tried running the code online using github codespaces to check if the problem was local. (Spoiler, it wasn't). How can I fix this error?

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9448

Comment: I've done this, however when i run "npm start" i get no errors, but as soon as i open the app it crashes instantly with no error message or nothing